# How to work on amazon aws ec2 reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently I have purchased a reserved instance EC2 t2.medium.

There is no option to start and stop, whereas my freetire has all the features including stop, start, with public ip, etc.

Please Suggest me, how to use and work around reserved instance||

Answer (score 17):

Reseverd instances are not started or stopped, they merely present the reservation of an on-demand instance at a reduced price. In order to use your reserved instance, you just need to have an instance of the same type as your reserved one already launched, or launch an on-demand instance of the same type and the reservation will be allocated to your instance. The only thing you need to make sure is that the servers will be started in the same availability zone as your reserved instance (for example - if your reserved instance is for us-east-1c AZ you have to choose the same AZ for your on-demand instance)

To make sure you are using the full amount of reserved instances at your disposal, you can check the reports section of your ec2 dashboard. the EC2 Reserved Instance Utilization reports will show you the amount of reserved instance being utilized.

Comment: This is correct, overall, but there's actually one problem with this answer.  After purchasing a reserved instance, there is no need to launch a *new* instance if you already have an on-demand instance running that matches the characteristics of the one you just reserved.  While this should be obvious from reading the documentation, I would respectfully suggest that the answer should reflect that aspect -- the new reserved instance pricing will automatically be applied by the billing department to any single matching, pre-existing on-demand instance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, that's true, I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess, my question is right, if the suggested answer is found to be correct. I was wondering, why stackoverflow bees have down voted my question!!

Comment: I'm assuming someone downvoted it because question on SO should be related to programming, and your question is more directed at server administration - Server Fault might have been a more suitable location for your queations. 
I personally disagree, and I think AWS related question are ok in SO, until a more suitable, DevOps related group will emerge.
This way or that, the person who downvoted you should've left a comment as well, explaining his criticism.

Comment: While we're on that subject, if you've found my answer helpful, please mark it as the right answer.